# Date.format(Date) vs. Date.format(Object)

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I found **java.text.DateFormat** has 2 methods to format date. One is taking Date parameter, the other taking Object parameter. I checked DateFormat source code and it seems that they call different internal methods.

**My question is which method (way) I should use to format Date? WAY 1 vs WAY 2**

**Here is my code:**

```
 Object dateObject; // This is an instance of java.util.Date

 DateFormat df = this.createDateFormat();

 String formatted1 = df.format ( (Date) dateObject );  // WAY 1

 String formatted2 = df.format ( dateObject );  // WAY 2 -- Calling different internal method.
```

NOTE that, For WAY 1, I cast dateObject to java.util.Date

Anyone has any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. The `format(Object)` is part of the base `Format` interface; `DateFormat` also provides a `format(Date)` for clarity.

Ultimately, the `format(Object)` version calls `DateFormat.format(Object, StringBuffer, FieldPosition)` which, from [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/DateFormat.java#DateFormat.format%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.StringBuffer%2Cjava.text.FieldPosition%29), will attempt the following, in order:

- If object is a `Date`, cast to `Date` and perform same conversion as `format(Date)`.
- If object is a `Number`, construct a `new Date(((Number)object).longValue())` then format that.
- Otherwise, throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

That first point makes `format(Object)` identical to `format(Date)` when the object is a `Date`.

In your case, since date is an `Object`, I would simply use `format(Object)` because it is less verbose, and `format(Object)` will do the cast for you.

Comment: @Loc When in doubt, and when the documentation itself isn't specific, you can always head to http://grepcode.com/ to check out various versions of the source online (or look at the JDK source if it was included in your distribution). The documentation for [`DateFormat.format(Object, StringBuffer, FieldPosition)`](http://bit.ly/1eexL5y) actually does sort of guarantee this behavior, although its connection to `format(Object)` is not immediately obvious.

Comment: Yes. I checked the code again and your explain is correct. I checked before but I didn't see that function. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your WAY1 method is from `DateFormat` class, WAY2 method is from `Format` class (**ancestor** of `DateFormat`). I think both ways calls format method from `DateFormat` so **both ways are equivalent.**